Is there a midcircle of a regular polygon?
I know that all regular polyhedra have an insphere which is tangent to all its faces, a midsphere which is tangent to all its edges, and a circumsphere which contains all its vertices.  I also know that all regular polygons have an incircle which is tangent to all its edges and a circumcircle which contains all its vertices.  Does a regular polygon only have two such circles rather than three since it is 2-dimensional rather than 3-dimensional, or is there a third "midcircle" measurement I'm not aware of that has a different relationship with a regular polygon?  I couldn't find any mention of a midcircle after a quick internet search but would like to know for sure whether or not it exists.

Your dimension count imtuition is right. There is no third circle for a regular polygon. In four dimenstions there will be four hyperspheres, and so on.
You may be interested(*) in the fact that

Schläfli showed that there are six regular convex polytopes in 4
dimensions. Five of them can be seen as analogous to the Platonic
solids: the 4-simplex (or pentachoron) to the tetrahedron, the
hypercube (or tesseract) to the cube, the 4-orthoplex (or
hexadecachoron or 16-cell) to the octahedron, the 120-cell to the
dodecahedron, and the 600-cell to the icosahedron. The sixth, the
24-cell, can be seen as a transitional form between the hypercube and
16-cell, analogous to the way that the cuboctahedron and the rhombic
dodecahedron are transitional forms between the cube and the
octahedron.
In five and more dimensions, there are exactly three regular
polytopes, which correspond to the tetrahedron, cube and octahedron.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope
(*) Your stackexchange profile suggests this is not news to you.
